# How to handle the buffer length input and return value size mismatch in send()?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, posix

How does the send()* function handle -
`ssize_t retval = send(sock, buf, SIZE_MAX, 0);`

If send is successfully able to send SIZE_MAX bytes then the return type isn't big enough to handle such a big value (typically SSIZE_MAX ~= SIZE_MAX/2).

Will the send() function limit itself to send only SSIZE_MAX bytes in this case?

* `ssize_t send(int socket, const void *buffer, size_t length, int flags);`
- https://linux.die.net/man/3/send

Comment: Similar question for `write`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722999/will-write2-always-write-less-than-or-equal-to-ssize-max: *"If the value of nbyte is greater than {SSIZE_MAX}, the result is implementation-defined."*

Comment: @MartinR - Should I assume this extends to send() or is there any documentation which mentions that send() has the same limits as write()?

Comment: I assume so, in particular because *"If fildes refers to a socket, write() shall be equivalent to send() with no flags set."* – But I do not have a definite reference.

Comment: @MartinR Would [the POSIX `send()` reference document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html) count as a "definitive source"?

Comment: @AndrewHenle - That's great, since the 'flags' argument is almost always 0 in my application. But I do wonder what happens when 'flags' is non-zero?!

Comment: @MartinR - Please add your comment as an answer.

Comment: @work.bin: I do not have an answer that I am sufficiently confident of. Even in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html I cannot see a definite answer to your question  how a length>SSIZE_MAX would be handled.

Comment: @MartinR - It at least makes explicit the fact that when flags is 0 write() is used, which implies implementation-defined behaviour in my case, which further implies that the programmer keen on portability has to ensure that the length parameter is never greater than SSIZE_MAX.

Comment: How does one ever obtain a valid buffer that is SIZE_MAX bytes long?

Answer (score 1):

The only way for `send` to conform to the requirement that it return the number of bytes sent upon successful completion and that it return −1 if it failed is for `send` never to send more than `SSIZE_MAX` bytes. When the `length` parameter exceeds `SSIZE_MAX`, `send` must either fail or return a length less than requested.

Comment: Are you basing this off any normative text (either C or POSIX standard) or are you just stating your expectations? Because another (possibly) valid send() implementation could very well choose to send only SSIZE_MAX bytes.

Comment: @work.bin: I have updated the answer to allow for partial transmission. That `send` permits partial transmission is not clear from its specification but appears to be so based on other sources. This conclusion is dictated by logic. Since `send` must return failure or the number of bytes sent, it cannot send more than can be represented its return type.

Comment: Expectation of logical implementation of 'holes' in the specification is not something I want to count on when trying to write portable code. It is eminently possible that the implementer of send() could have done a `return  length;` at the end of successful transmission since the fact that length could be a number bigger than the capacity of the return type could have simply escaped his/her attention.

Comment: @work.bin: Previously you asked for a basis in specifications. Now you raise the spectre of a buggy implementation. If you want to guess at bugs that might exist, without actual instances, then work around them as you wish. That does not seem like a useful exercise.

Comment: Aside: Can `ssize_t` be wide enough (e.g. 64-bit) such that it includes the entire `size_t` range (e.g.(32-bit)?  I suppose it depends on what standard `ssize_t` originates.  Here it is POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

send() in length is limited by ability to handle the message by underlying protocol. return is signed to report on error contition so negative numbers are errors. So theoretically it is limited but there is no yet protocol to transfer SIZE_MAX message.

Comment: No protocol used by send() can transfer a 65535-bytes sized message?

Comment: On my Linux (x64) it is 18446744073709551615UL, are you talking about 16-bit platform? Anyway in case it can split, it will use portion of buffer applicable for proto below to fill it's buffer and return how much it sent or error.

Answer (score -1):

`send()` will attempt to send `SIZE_MAX` bytes from the buffer pointed to by `buf`.  However, `SIZE_MAX` is basically an indication of the largest value that the pointer type of an architecture could conceivably represent.  So it is usually at minimum the size of the entire address space, if not more.